# "Хоть глаз выколи" — запятая нужна?

Tags: пунктуация

*"На улице хоть глаз выколи".* Нужна запятая в этом предложении?

Comment: Слушайте, ну в каком месте вы здесь придумали запятую? После какого слова? Просто интересно, вы реально такие вопросы задаёте или просто не знаете, чего бы еще спросить. Если второе, спросите еще надо ли писать корову через ять.

Comment: послушайте, вы к моим постам не ровно дышите, я смотрю...

Comment: И не мечтайте. Вы слишком похожи на своих предшественников, чобы Вас как-то выделять среди череды однообразных ботов. ***Так где здесь запятая-то  сомнительная?***

Comment: )))))))))))))))

Comment: Ну короче, сами не знаете, о чем спросить.

Answer (score 2):

На улице **хоть глаз выколи ( = очень темно)**.

Не нужна запятая, устойчивый оборот в значении одного слова.

Вот пришла и тёмная ночь: кругом его **хоть глаз выколи**, а у него под догами светлехонько. [С. Т. Аксаков. Aленький цветочек (1858)]. Темнота **хоть глаз выколи**, ничего не видно. [Шамиль Тарпищев. Самый долгий матч (1999)]. Темень была **хоть глаз выколи**... [Георгий Владимов. Три минуты молчания (1969)].  Темь **хоть глаз выколи**...и ничего не поймешь, ничего не видать! [И. А. Бунин. Сверчок (1911)]

Сравнить: На улице темно, **хоть глаз выколи.** Здесь оборот уточняет уже названный признак, запятая ставится.

Как и любое слово, оборот может играть **различную синтаксическую роль** (обстоятельство, именная часть сказуемого, отдельное придаточное предложение и т.д.), возможно авторское обособление тире при наличии паузы:

А ночь ― **хоть глаз выколи** и дождь холит. [И. А. Бунин. Ночной разговор (1911)]. Ночь была темна, так темна, что **хоть глаз выколи**. [Ал. Алтаев (М. В. Ямщикова). Гроза на Москве (1914)]

Comment: А Вы считаете, что так можно говорить? Именно "**на улице** хоть глаз выколи", а не, напр., "кругом его". или Вы считаете, что это почти одно и то же?

Comment: Но почему так нельзя говорить?  Эта фраза обозначает "на улице очень темно", именно в таком виде она встречается во многих литературных текстах. В то же время  возможны самые различные конструкции с эти оборотом.

Comment: Верю, верю... наверно, ошибался, значит. Хорошо бы ещё другие подтвердили, что для них тоже это нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна:

***На улице хоть глаз выколи.***

Возможна постановка интонационного тире:

***На улице  — хоть глаз выколи.***

Примеры из книг:

***На улице хоть глаз выколи***, лишь где-то вдали отсветы береговых факелов. (Андрей Дорофеев. Возвращение в Атлантиду.)

*Луны были закрыты облаками, **на улице — хоть глаз выколи**, темень несусветная.* 
(Евгений Щепетнов. Нищий. Дикие земли.)

Comment: А сама фраза нормально звучит, да?

Comment: Да нормальная фраза, разговорная, образная.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Оно и к лучшему. Мне уже нравится так.) Не знаю, почему решил, что так не говорят. Видимо, из-за буквального восприятия: *пойди на улицу и выколи кому-нибудь глаз.*)))

Answer (score 1):

Так не говорят (я так думал, но, похоже, неправильно). Можно сказать так:

*"На улице тьма/темень(,) хоть глаз выколи"* или *"На улице темно, хоть глаз выколи"* или *"На улице ничего не видно, хоть глаз выколи".*

Что касается запятой, хороший вопрос. Она нужна в двух последних примерах, судя по примерам из Нацкорпуса и Google-книг. Но с *"тьмой", "теменью", "темнотой"* примерно одинаковое количество примеров там *с запятой и без.*